# InnoDB row level locks without SELECTs?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

I have several (>30) MySQL clients inserting into InnoDB tables concurrently. I keep encountering lock wait timeouts and can't figure out why. Here is the situation:

Each client runs the following transactions repeatedly:

```
Start transaction
Insert one row into table A
for i = 1 to 22
  Do some time-consuming calculation (30 sec)
  Insert results into table B
end
Commit transaction
```

The lock wait timeouts happen when inserting into table A. Table B's primary key is the same as table A's augmented by another field. Table B has a foreign key into table A.

There are no SELECTs anywhere. No row is inserted twice. Transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ.

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS shows up to 36 row-level locks for some active transactions.

I do not understand why there are any locks. Can anyone give me some hints as to what's going on?

Comment: I think that's because of MySQL's "gap locking". It locks rows that aren't there in order to prepare for inserts "near by" (e.g. with the next higher auto-increment). If I'm not mistaken this has something to do with the clustered index that is build from the primary key. But I could be totally mistaken as well...

Comment: According to my understanding of the manual, several concurrent inserts into the same gap should be possible if the inserted rows are disjoint:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html

"A type of gap lock called an insertion intention gap lock is set by INSERT operations prior to row insertion. This lock signals the intent to insert in such a way that multiple transactions inserting into the same index gap need not wait for each other if they are not inserting at the same position within the gap."

Comment: I believe row lock will be held on master table (if I understood you right, it's `A`) when you insert a record into details (`B`) until you commit/rollback transaction

Comment: But what would be locked in A? Presumably the row corresponding to the inserts in B, right? That shouldn't be a problem since each transaction involves only exactly one row in A and a few corresponding rows in B. I simply don't understand why the transactions interact.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL is taking too much of the `innodb buffer pool` size for your table locking.

Insert `innodb_buffer_pool_size=2g` in `my.cnf` file, which is most probably in `/etc/mysql/`